# Creating ref types for enums in Rust, same as Path for PathBuf

Tags: rust

In Rust, `String` matches `str` slice type, and `PathBuf` -> `Path`. With some built-in trait magic, it is possible to get value by a corresponding reference, which is actually a different type:

```rust
let mut hs = HashSet::new();
hs.insert(String::from("hello"));  // insert owned String value
let get_by_ref = hs.get("hello");  // retrieve by str reference
```

I am writing a generic collection that should accept ANY type that has this "obj/ref" duality, accepting any `&Q` such that `T: Borrow<Q>` -- similar to all collection types.

Is there a similar mechanism I can use when working with enums?  Given a collection that stores enums with owned types, how can I have a corresponding "non-owned" references similar to `str` and `Path`?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone)]
enum Value {
    Str(String),
    Int(i32),
}

let mut hs = HashSet::new();

// insert owned value
hs.insert(Value::Str(String::from("hello")));

// retrieve by reference
let get_by_ref = hs.get(???);
```

Should I perhaps implement a corresponding "ref enum type" and have a conversion method?  In that case, what traits would I need?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
enum ValueRef<'a> {
    Str(&'a str),
    Int(i32),
}
```

Comment: Yeah actually I came to a very similar solution, but embedding the `Cow::Borrowed` as a variant in `Value`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=925d17731c44fa4f045d516585d87c8c

Comment: Unfortunately Cow might not work for my case.  I need a generic method that can accept anything.  Essentially my collection (that may use HashSet underneath) should be able to store **ANY** type pair (String/str, PathBuf/Path, Value/ValueRef)

Comment: I modified the question to clarify this - I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: `Cow` is not the only answer on the other post, basically you are asking how to implement `Borrow<U> for T` where T  and  U have nothing in common. `T` needs to contain `U` otherwise it is not possible to implement with safe Rust.

Comment: @ÖmerErden the `T` and `U` do have something in common - e.g. `Value::Str(String)` -> `ValueRef::Str(str)`, with `str` pointing to the same memory. I have been studying the dups' `enum ConfigKey`, which is a bit similar, but it doesn't answers how to make it support existing pairs like `str/String` -- that answer has its own `trait Key` for all the magic with `dyn` handling.

Comment: Ok we already have solution for `str/String` pair, but you requested for **ANY** pair, `T` and `U` is can be considered an any pair where `T` and `U` have nothing in common. That's the point that we don't have safe Rust solution, since we cannot implement the `Borrow<U> for T`

Comment: @ÖmerErden ah, i see what you mean. I am OK to provide the Borrow implementation for any custom pair I write, but that's exactly what I couldn't write for some reason for the `ValueRef<'a>` case, hence was looking for a working example of such borrow

Comment: @ÖmerErden basically I would like this to compile and run: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74f64580959a5d0afcaf09dc46335d9c

Comment: There is just no way to do this without merging `ValueRef` into `Value` (or doing something similar via `Cow`).